# Creating temporary tables inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I need to create two temporary tables inside a stored procedure, and wherever I put the `CREATE` statements MySQL gives me that nonsense syntax error `missing 'end'`.
[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html) *useful* page says nothing about where to put the `CREATE` statements, though I have everything else is in the desired order.
I also would like to **note** that only the semicolon after second `CREATE` statement is recognized as a syntax error, if I swap them, the error is still in the latter statement.
[Here's my code](http://pastie.org/10228618), but I guess only first 20 lines matter.
The statements I was (unsuccessfully) trying to add:

```
-- temporary tables
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE filtered
LIKE seances;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE probs (
solution_id INT,
priori DOUBLE);
```

Comment: @BK435 I am new to using mysql, could you please enlighten me about delimiters? Or provide some kind of documentation?

Comment: Seems like line 17 would be where you would create temp tables.  You can always work around the declaration order by nesting everything in an additional `BEGIN`/`END` block and putting your temp table creation statements immediately between the existing `BEGIN` and the new one you add.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot wow, how unobvious. However, it works, thank you. If you post this as an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating temporary table inside stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444231/creating-temporary-table-inside-stored-procedure), though it's hard to say when the link is dead... another reason we post self-contained questions.